# How can I install Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

Now I am using Ubuntu 20.04, but now I want to install Windows 10 alongside my 20.04 LTS.
I am trying to make a partition but I can't make it.  Can you tell me the solution?
When I try to install Windows, it shows the disk is a NTFS file, Windows can not install on this drive.

What is the solution?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS system with Ubuntu in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? Windows has to be in same boot mode, but instructions lot different if UEFI or BIOS. And Windows should be in same boot mode as Ubuntu, particularly if on same drive. And Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode since Windows 8 released in 2012, so UEFI preferred if newer hardware.

Answer (score 0):

*****The easiest way***** 
*****first backup important data*****

i suggest removing ubuntu
then try to install window 10 first
after the installation of windows 10
install ubuntu 20 again
this time select on install alongside windows 10
this will install window 10 with ubuntu
after the installation restart your pc
you will see a menu called grub

in the last you will see windows 10

now you can run windows 10 alongside ubuntu

by other way like resizing main extended partition ext4 will not
work as window 10 will install and it will stop ext4 partition to stop
loading and will load window

Answer (score 0):

#### Installation of the `dual-boot` system:

0. *Important: first install `windows`, then install `linux`!!*
1. Format the hard drive by yourself (for example with `acronis disk director`). Create one primary MBR bootable `ntfs` partition and install `windows` on it:

   ```
   | windows c:                                        |
   |---------------------------------------------------|
   | ntfs                                              |
   ```
2. After installing `windows` resize (by yourself again) the partition to 20 Gb (it should be enough) and move it to the third place, add the first and second partitions (primary MBR too). Make the `linux root` partition bootable:

   ```
   | linux swap | linux root | windows c: | linux home |
   |------------|------------|------------|------------|
   | RAM x2     | 10 Gb      | 20 Gb      | any        |
   ```

   Fourth partition - user's files `linux home` or `windows d:` (primary MBR too). In the later versions of `linux` you can instead of the `swap` partition use the file in the `root` partition (in `windows` this is the `pagefile.sys` on the disk `c:`). Some motherboards require an `efi` partition (100 Mb is enough).
3. Specify in the [`c:\\boot.ini`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLDR#boot.ini) file, that `windows` was moved to the third partition:

   ```
   multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(3)\WINDOWS
   ```
4. Install `linux` without worrying that `windows` will stop working after that. Further operations with the hard disk (if necessary) perform from `linux`, or using external `bootable` software.

---

It is better if the first 3 partitions are located on the separate `ssd` disks, and even better - on removable ones, but in this case you should set boot sequence in the BIOS of the motherboard.